# How to get user SecurityGroups alone in Azure MVC WebAPI using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I have the below code which can get me the list of groups from Azure Active Directory user belongs to.

```
string UserPrincipalName = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName;

List<string> result = new List<string>();
WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(UserPrincipalName);

foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
{
     try
     {
        result.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception ex) { }
}
result.Sort();
```

Is there a way I can request to get only the security groups from it in the call . And is that also possible to pass a security group and verify if the SG is mapped to the user in the request?